# R: Some hints on when a function understands its argument?

Tags: r, function, lapply

I'm trying to write a function I can apply to a string vector or list instead of writing a loop. My goal is to run a regression for different endogenous variables and save the resulting tables. Since experienced R users tell us we should learn the apply functions, I want to give it a try. Here is my attempt:

**Broken Example:**

```
library(ExtremeBounds)
Data <- data.frame(var1=rbinom(30,1,0.2),var2=rbinom(30,1,0.2),var3=rnorm(30),var4=rnorm(30),var5=rnorm(30),var6=rnorm(30))

spec1 <- list(y=c("var1"),freevars=("var3"),doubtvars=c("var4","var5"))
spec2 <- list(y=c("var2"),freevars=("var4"),doubtvars=c("var3","var5","var6"))
specs <- c("spec1","spec2")

myfunction <- function(x){
eba <- eba(data=Data, y=x$y, 
       free=x$freevars, 
       doubtful=x$doubtvars, 
       reg.fun=glm, k=1, vif=7, draws=50, se.fun = se.robust, weights = "lri", family = binomial(logit))

output <- eba$bounds
output <- output[,-(3:7)]
}

lapply(specs,myfunction)
```

Which gives me an error that makes me guess that R does not understand when `x` should be `"spec1"` or `"spec2"`. Also, I don't quite understand what lapply would try to collect here. Could you provide me with some best practice/hints how to communicate such things to R?

error: `Error in x$y : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

**Working example:**

Here is a working example for `spec1` without using apply that shows what I'm trying to do. I want to loop this example through 7 specs but I'm trying to get away from loops. The output does not have to be saved as a csv, a list of all outputs or any other collection would be great!

```
eba <- eba(data=Data, y=spec1$y, 
       free=spec1$freevars, 
       doubtful=spec1$doubtvars, 
       reg.fun=glm, k=1, vif=7, draws=50, se.fun = se.robust, weights = "lri", family = binomial(logit))
output <- eba$bounds
output <- output[,-(3:7)]
write.csv(output, "./Results/eba_pmr.csv")
```

Comment: what is the error message you're getting?

Comment: probably best to define specs as `specs <- list(spec1,spec2)` rather than as a string (then it works) . Maybe better practice to define `x$y` as `x[['y']]` etc and so on, and explicitly return the object (although in this instance it doesnt seem to matter)

Comment: or using your original `specs` this might work `lapply(mget(specs),myfunction)`

Comment: actually, your second solution is even better because the resulting list preserves the different `specs` names. Thanks a lot! Do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: Feel free to write it up Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments of @user20650, the solution is quite simple:

In the lapply command, use `lapply(mget(specs),myfunction)` which gets the names of the list elements of specs instead of the lists themselves.

Alternatively, one could define `specs` as a list: `specs <- list(spec1,spec2)` but that has the downside that the lapply command will return a list where the different specifications are numbered. The first version keeps the names of the specifications (`spec1` and `spec2`) which which makes work with the resulting list much easier.